# Omit assembler keyword for assembler functions

Tags: freepascal

Is there a compiler switch I'm not seeing that would allow me to omit the assembler keyword from assembler functions?

How I do it now, using example from FPC docs:

```
function geteipasebx : pointer;assembler;  
asm  
  movl (%esp),%ebx  
  ret  
end;
```

How I would like to do it:

```
function geteipasebx : pointer;
asm  
  movl (%esp),%ebx  
  ret  
end;
```

Can this be done?

EDIT:
compiler source file PSUB.PAS line 170:

```
{ do we have an assembler block without the po_assembler?
  we should allow this for Delphi compatibility (PFV) }
 if (token=_ASM) and (m_delphi in current_settings.modeswitches) then
  include(current_procinfo.procdef.procoptions,po_assembler);

{ Handle assembler block different }
 if (po_assembler in current_procinfo.procdef.procoptions) then ...
```

I believe this part of the source code of free pascal means that this can only be done in {$MODE DELPHI}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done. You have to set the compiler compatibility mode to `DELPHI` and to redefine the asm syntax to `ATT`, since the mode `DELPHI` will override it to `INTEL`.

more concretly, the program:

```
program Project1;
{$MODE DELPHI}
{$ASMMODE ATT}
function geteipasebx : pointer;
asm
  movl (%esp),%ebx
  ret
end;

var
  p: pointer;
begin
  p := geteipasebx;
end.
```

compiles and run fine.

Comment: Ohhh, how interesting, thanks! And is there a way to do this but while being in {$MODE FPC} ? I tried a bunch of {$MODESWITCH} options but couldnt find one that enabled to omit this keyword in FPC mode rather then DELPHI mode.

Comment: I don't think that the DELPHI mode is only a set of compiler switch: The **assembler** attribute is probably like the **specialize** keyword, there is no switch for that, it's the dialect. But I might be wrong.

Comment: I'll wait a day or two in case someone can figure this out before accepting your answer. I've been able to add all the features of {$MODE DELPHI} I care about to {$MODE FPC} with various compiler switches, this isn't necessary at all but would be a nice convenience to make code more readable.

Comment: I edited my question with the info I found in the free pascal source code, which seems to indicate that your answer and comment are right. Therefore I will accept your answer. Thanks!